# Prob. 15, Sec. 3.10 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book: $\Vert T^2 \Vert =\Vert T \Vert^2$ if $T$ is normal?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $T \colon H \to H$ be a bounded linear operator, and let $T^*$ denote the Hilbert adjoint operator of $T$.

I can show that if $T$ is normal (i.e. $T T^* = T^* T$), then $\Vert T^* x \Vert = \Vert Tx \Vert$ for all $x \in H$.

Moreover, if $H$ is complex and if $\Vert T^* x \Vert = \Vert Tx \Vert$ for all $x \in H$, then $T$ is normal.

Also, we have $\Vert T^2 \Vert \leq \Vert T \Vert^2$.

Now suppose that $T$ is normal.

Then how to show that $\Vert T^2 \Vert = \Vert T \Vert^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us proceed by the definition of the norm of an operator and the fact that if $T$ is normal then $\|T^*x\| = \|Tx\|$ for all $x\in H$. And also you might know that $\|T^*T\| = \|T\|^2$. Using these three things what you get is the following
\begin{align}
\|T^2\| &= \sup_\limits{\|z\|=1}\|T^2z\|\\
&=\sup_\limits{\|z\|=1}\|TTz\|\\
&=\sup_\limits{\|z\|=1}\|T^*Tz\|& & (\text{because $\|T^*x\| = \|Tx\|$ })\\
&=\|T^*T\|\\
&=\|T\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: how do we derive $\Vert T^* T \Vert = \Vert T \Vert^2$?

Comment: I think this has been done in kreyszig in section $3.9$

Comment: are you from Pakistan or India? Where are you from?

Comment: i am from  India....

Comment: which place? What do you do? Oh yes, I remember! It's Theorem 3.9-4 (e). Thanks.